# Data transfer from One database to another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-3.0

I am looking for an idea or some direction. I have to transfer data from one database to another both are structurally and schema wise same.

Its a complete database with maybe 70 tables and having relationship between tables at different levels. Even though i ' m going to mess up the identity when i move across database but as of now i am ok with it.

Idea which i thought was to load required data from all table into an XML and then create connection to second database and push data from this XML its kind of repeated and not best way at all. So looking for direction.

Can i use entity framework for this somehow??

I cannot use SSIS for this it has to be C# Sorry.

Comment: Can you create a linked server?  What database?

Comment: @blam : Its is SQl sever 2008 R2. ya i can create a linked sever. So you are saying i can create a linked server and read from one sever into table of another server.

Comment: Yes it is slick.  You just have a 4 part name.  My experience is you get better performance if you connect to the server you are writing to.

Comment: @Blam: just now i noticed databases are in different domain and i m not able to create linked server. Any thoughts on this

Comment: You should be able to if you set up domain trust of use SQL authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a linked server as stated in the comments to your question.  You seemed to indicate that you know how to do this, but in case not, you can do this from SQL Server Management Studio by drilling down to "Server Objects > Linked Servers" beneath your source database on the source database server, then right-click, "New Linked Server", etc.

Then you would use a statement like this, for example, from your C# code:

```
insert into DestServer.DBName.dbo.TableName
select * from SourceServer.DBName.dbo.TableName
```

Assuming you are connected to 'SourceServer' and that 'SourceServer' maintains a linked server object pointing to 'DestServer'.  Note: you don't actually need to use the fully-qualified name for the table on 'SourceServer', but I've put it there for clarity.  I.E. you could also do this:

```
insert into DestServer.DBName.dbo.TableName
select * from TableName
```

Don't forget to setup the permissions properly in your linked server object so that your query can write to the table in the destination server.  You can do this any number of ways, and often (because I work in a small environment where it's maintained by just me and a couple other folks) I just use the "sa" login:

[image]

Comment: just now i noticed databases are in different domain and i m not able to create linked server. Any thoughts on this

Comment: If this is a one-time transfer operation, you could restore a backup of one or other of the databases on the other server, then both databases would be local, then you could do this without even needing a linked server setup.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, can use linked servers in .NET.
You just use the 4 part name.
What you can do in TSQL in SSMS you can do in a .NET SQLcommand.

My experience is that you get better performance connecting to the server you are writing to.

Comment: Thanks Blam ..Is there a way that i can do using entity framework or some Other ORM?? just for curiosity

Comment: Not sure if an ORM would see the linked server - Try.   I don't use ORMs.